# Response time graphite monitoring for url with query string?

Tags: namespaces, monitoring, graphite

I need to measure the response times of my API endpoints using graphite but I'm unsure with the namespace.

Suppose I have one endpoint to measure

- `/results/`
- `/results/?organization_id=100&limit=100`

Assuming I have tons of results, the first endpoint response time will be much slower than the second one (and I need to measure both endpoints).

So how should I create the namespace for this in graphite? Is it common to include query params in the namespace (e.g. `project.results.get.organization_id=100&limit=100` and `project.results.get.all`)? One of my concern to include the query params is that the namespace will blew up if query params are continuously changing (different organization, different limit, different field, etc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the best metric naming scheme (namespaces) depends on what do you want to use these metrics for.

For example, assuming that in your case what you want to check is the average, min and max time for the `/results/` endpoint whatever the query parameters are, you would use a single metric name like `stats.results.timer`. This is useful to monitor how long requests are taking and make sure they are fast enough.

On the other hand, if you consider that querying `/results/` with and without querystring parameters have two very different timings and you want to consider them separately, you could create individual metrics for the different kind of parameters included, like `stats.results.organization_id__limit`, `stats.results.organization_id`, etc. I wouldn't ever think of including the parameter values in the metric name, since it would indeed potentially blow up the metrics namespace.

I would definitely go for the first option, but again it depends a lot on your concrete use case.